# Delete Files with Task Scheduler using ForFiles

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to delete all folders and files on a nightly basis using task scheduler.  I am using the following command in the actions:

Program/Script: `forfiles`
Arguments: `/S /P C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rd /s /q @file"`

This is not deleting any file or folder.  What do i have missing in this example?

This seems to work but does throw an error:    `/S /P "C:\Users\Sales\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup"  /C "cmd /c rd /s /q @file`

Error:

```
C:\Users\david>forfiles /S /P "C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup"  /C "cmd /c rd /s /q @file

ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\david>
```

Comment: Ill add as well that the process just stays running with no output

Answer (score 0):

Why are you searching subdirectories when you plan on clobbering everything with "rd /s /q"?

What you ***might*** (are probably) be seeing is this:

1. ***forfiles*** builds a list of files to work with:
   say... "**C:\This**"  and "**C:\This\That**"
2. You get "***C:\This***" handed to you
3. You delete "***C:\This***" recursively
4. You get "***C:\This\That***" handed to you.
5. You get an error deleting it because it doesn't exist.

One other condition can happen too!  There can be a file handle open while enumerating the tree so when you try to delete "***C:\This***", "***C:\This\That***" is still locked open by forfiles.  I don't know if forfiles is written to circumvent this but I have ***for sure*** run into this while programming.

Suggestion:  Drop the /S from ***forfiles*** (best) OR add "blah blah blah.. ***if exist @file***" blah blah blah (not best).